# How does this JS line work?

Tags: javascript, comparison, operators

I was reading the code of a third party javascript library and it had the following line:

```
x2 = x1 - minWidth * (x2 < x1 || -1);
```

x1, x2, and minWidth are all numbers

I am wondering about the `(x2 < x1 || -1)` part.  How does the comparison operator work here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's look at short-circuiting. Say you have a line like

```
var A = B || C;
```

If `B` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value then `A` will be set to `B`. If it is not, then `A` will be equal to `C`.

Re-applying that to your situation, if `x2 < x1` is true, the result of that expression will be `true`. Otherwise, the result will be `-1`.

Next, we consider how type casting works in Javascript. Anytime you multiply using a given value, that value is coerced to a number. For `true`, that number is `1`.

Ultimately, it means "if x2 >= x1, flip the sign of the min width."

Answer (score 2):

In english, it's saying if `x2` is less than `x1` return true, otherwise return -1. `true` converts to 1, so it boils down to `minWidth * 1 or -1`

Example with numbers:

`minWidth = 5`, `x1 = 3`, `x2 = 2`. `x2 = 5 * (true OR -1)`

reduced: `x2 = 5*true` = `x2 = 5*1`

So it's a way to yield a negative or positive value conversion.

Comment: that makes sense...thank you for explaining in plain english

Comment: MikeC's answer has a good link about truthy values that you should read. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The verbose equivalant to that line would be something like,

```
if(x2 < x1){
    x2 = x1 - minWidth * 1;
} else {
    x2 = x1 - minwidth * -1;
}
```

In JavaScript, `true` is also equal to 1.  Knowing that, you can use that value to shortcut some logic.

Additionally, the || binary operator will continue on as soon as it reaches a `true`.  Everything that follows the true inside the condition statement will be ignored.  This is called short-circuiting.

This is what is happening in your example.  Since the value of that part of the condition when true is also equivalent to 1, the author saved a step and just used that value.